# "The app isn't available, Try again." on TestFlight

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to set up Internal Testing for my iOS app. I've submitted the build to the app store, and it is awaiting review happily. I have a group of Technical users in iTunes Connect with Internal Testing available, and I have invited them all to test the app.

However, when any of use click the button in the e-mail (using the Mail app on the relevant device), Testflight opens and then says "The app isn't available. Try again."

Googling for this error has been completely futile (it's a googlewhack!) - is there a simple delay before the app is available? It has been several hours. Has anybody else experienced this and can maybe tell me what step I have missed?

Comment: I'm getting the same error now. No info to troubleshoot as usual!

Comment: Deploying an app to the Apple App Store reminds me of 90s-era web site deployment.  The Apple user experience was a bit, shall we say, underwhelming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing all Internal Testers. Then I disabled Testflight Beta Testing on the Pre-release page.

Then I enabled Pre-release, navigated to Internal Testers and selected users to invite - and that invite worked fine.

Comment: Same for me. Seems like a new bug, cause 2 weeks ago everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

The app must reviewed before you can start distributing your beta.

> Apps made available to external testers require a Beta App Review and must comply with the full App Store Review Guidelines before testing can begin. A **review is required** for new versions of your app that contain significant changes. Up to 10 apps can be tested at a time, internally or externally.

[TestFlight Beta Testing](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/testflight/)

Comment: The review is only required for external beta testers, not Internal Testers.